# What is the name of these trigonometric problems?

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

[image: the problems]

[image: problems]

I'm self teaching myself precalc over the summer and I have to learn some trigonometry. I wanted just to know the names of problems similar to these so I can find a video to these. 
Thanks.

Comment: Trigonometry...

Comment: I have read the word "goniometric equations" in a german math-book, not sure whether this name is common. The exercises shown here have a lot to do with calculus.

Comment: Trigonometry is a broad topic to search. Can you be more specific what in trigonometry?

Comment: The wordings are not unique: **#13**, Graphing trigonometric functions; **#14, 16**, Multiple angle/compound angle formulae; **#15**, Relation between trigonometric functions; **#17**, Trigonometric equations.

Comment: You need to take a deep dive in trignometry. [Start with it here](http://www.mathportal.org/algebra/trigonometry/trigonometric-formula.php)

Comment: remove the images, use mathjax instead

Comment: They are called "miscellaneous trigonometric problems". (Ok, most of them are trigonometric equations.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a little historical remark : trigonometry has been considered a domain for itself till say the 1950s, and was a compulsory part of the curriculum of scientists. Now, it is a non central domain of interest, but it is still essential to know its basics...

Now, I answer your question. Here are some formulas and techniques that are rather fundamental ; in order that it helps you in your web search (for YouTube videos, for example), terms that can be considered as keywords are in bold. I have chosen to present the following points in terms of abilities, in decreasing order of importance, in my own experience :

- be able to work with radians instead of degrees (but be able to make conversion between the two systems).
- be familiar with **unit circle**, e.g., use it to quickly retrieve values of $\cos, \sin, \tan$ of **simple angles** $0,\pi/6,\pi/4,\pi/3,\pi/2$, and/or  retrieve different elementary properties such as $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$,  $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$, etc.
- master **addition formulas**: $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\sin(b)-\sin(a)\cos(b)$, etc.
- master **duplication formulas** $\sin(2a)=2\sin(a)\cos(a)$, $\cos(2a)=2 \cos^2 a-1=1-2 \sin^2 a=\cos^2 a - \sin^2 a$ which, of course, are consequences of addition formulas.
- be able to **find all solutions to some basic trigonometric equations** like $\cos(u)=\cos(v)$, $\sin(u)=\sin(v)$, $\tan(u)=\tan(v)$
- be able to understand and use the very fundamental **connection between trigonometry and complex numbers,** with $e^{ix}=\cos x+i \sin x$ and the derived **Euler formulas** $\cos(x)=\dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$, $\sin(x)=\dfrac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$, **de Moivre formula** $e^{inx}=(e^{ix})^n \ \iff \ \cos nx+i \sin nx=(\cos x+i \sin x)^n$, understand that the Taylor expansion $e^{ix}=1+ix+\dfrac{(ix)^2}{2}+\dfrac{(ix)^3}{3!}+...$ gives the Taylor expansions of $\cos x= 1- \dfrac{x^2}{2}+...$ and $\sin x= x- \dfrac{x^3}{3!}+...$ etc.
- be able to solve problems of **2D analytical geometry** involving angles. In particular being able to express a straight line under the form $y=\tan(\alpha)x+b$, or, even better, under the **normal form** : $ x \cos \varphi + y \sin \varphi - p = 0$ (with $\varphi=\alpha+\pi/2$) (http://www.math-only-math.com/straight-line-in-normal-form.html). Have an idea maybe on **3D analytical geometry**, very useful e.g., for computer vision.
- be able to solve trigonometric issues **in the circle** and **in the triangle** using important relationships like "central angle = $2 \times$ inscribed angle" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle) or **law of cosines** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) $a^2=b^2+c^2-2bc \cos(A)$ and **law of sines** $\tfrac{a}{\sin(A)}=\tfrac{b}{\sin(B)}=\tfrac{c}{\sin(C)}=2R$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines).
- be able to study/plot **functions involving circular functions** (= $\sin, \cos, \tan$...) or inverse circular functions. For that, you need basic differentiation formulas:  $\sin'(x)=\cos(x)=\sin(x+\pi/2)$, $\cos'(x)=-\sin(x)=\cos(x+\pi/2)$ (differentiation = phase shifting by $\pi/2$). And $\tan'(x)=\tfrac{1}{\cos^2(x)}=1+\tan^2(x)$
- have a certain practise of **inverse circular functions** $atan, acos, asin$ (sometimes named or misnamed $\tan^{-1}, \cos^{-1}, \sin^{-1}$), their derivatives, and some of their **tricky** sides due mainly to their domains of validity. The most important of them is $atan$.
- have an idea about the relationship between trigonometry and **rotation matrices** $\begin{pmatrix}\cos a&-\sin a\\ \sin a& \ \ \cos a \end{pmatrix}$, and more generally between trigonometry and **linear algebra**. This is connected to complex number representation.
- know the existence and technical interest of **half-angle formulas** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula), sometimes named **Weierstrass substitution**  with $t=tan(x/2)$ : $\cos(x)=(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)$, $\sin(x)=2t/(1+t^2)$ This is often a very convenient tool for transforming a trigonometrical probem into an algebraic problem. For example, one solves equation $3 \cos(x) + 4 \sin(x) = 1$ by using these formulas which give a quadratic equation in $t$.
- have some knowledge of the cousin functions $\sinh, \cosh, \tanh$ (hyperbolic trigonometry).
- have an idea of what the **harmonic oscillator** is (the basic differential equation $y''(t)=-\omega^2 y(t)$ having $\sin(\omega t)$ among its solutions).

Final remark: You have seen that I have only spoken about $\sin, \cos, \tan$ (and $acos, asin, atan$). No need for other functions like $\cot, \sec, csec$. You can do trigonometry without using them at all.

Comment: I have added some (minor) points that I had forgotten yesterday. Can you say me it answers your question ?

Comment: Yeah, sure. There's a lot of information that you've given me but after doing research myself I'm focusing on remembering reciprocal and pythagorean identities I think that helps be with my problems to a large extent.